# How do I correctly embed an <iframe> in Blazor? (Youtube)

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

A standard youtube embedded video using an `<iframe>` container on my Blazor page doesn't load correctly. Nothing is loaded.

```html
<iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/m8e-FF8MsqU' frameborder='0' allow='accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In my page the link is actually linked with a `@video` link as such, but the result is the same.

```html
<iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/@video' frameborder='0' allow='accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Looking at the source, a mostly empty `<html>` structure is built under `#document`.

```html
<html><head></head><body></body><link type="text/css" id="dark-mode" rel="stylesheet"><style type="text/css" id="dark-mode-custom-style"></style></html>
```

While in a normal HTML page the structure is filled with the content from Youtube. (Shortened)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  <html lang="en" dir="ltr" data-cast-api-enabled="true">
<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><style name="www-roboto" >@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:italic;font-weight:500;src:local('Roboto Medium Italic'),local('Roboto-MediumItalic'),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51S7ACc3CsTKlA.woff2)format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F,U+1C80-1C88,U+20B4,U+2DE0-2DFF,U+A640-A69F,U+FE2E-FE2F;}
```

How do I correctly embed an  so that it works as intended in Blazor?

Comment: How does the actual HTML document look when you inspect it in the browser when you try to add it?

Comment: @Threezool the second code quote is from the inspected blazor page when it's been added. A fairly empty <html> structure is generated as you can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Dani I confirmed that normally this actually works in blazor, in my specific case however, the problem was that I was using **single quotes** instead of **double quotes**. Changing the code made it work. Not sure if this is a bug in blazor or chrome for iframe, or intended functionality. If anyone has information on that I would happy know why.

Also, another reason I found for this behaviour is having `HTTP` instead of `HTTPS` in the url of the embedded page. It works fine in PHP even for youtube, but doesn't seem to work in blazor.

```html
<iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/@video" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 6):

I have tested YT `iframe` and it runs on both `blazorserver` and `blazorwasm` (Net Core 3 preview 9):

[image]

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@if (currentCount % 2 == 0)
{
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oJYGSy6fRic" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
}
else
{
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m8e-FF8MsqU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
}


@code {
    int currentCount = 0;

    void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Notice: I put `iframe` inside an `if` only for tests purposes, it runs also without the `if`.

Comment: Indeed it seems you are correct, I guess I should have tried it in a completely empty example project also before posting. It's weird though because it doesn't work in my project, I will have to investigate further what the difference could be and will report back. Woulde be great if there was some error/warning log to read that could point me in the right direction.

Comment: So! It turns out the problem was found in that I was using single quotes instead of double quotes.. not sure if that is an intended difference in blazor or html in general, since single quotes work fine in all other cases in blazor that I've tried, or if this is a bug in blazor?

Comment: I added an answer incase anyone else stumbles across this, if you like you can edit it into your answer and I will accept your answer instead. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I used `https` (`http` doesn't work).

Comment: I took the liberty to clean this up a little. Now I realise that it does not obviously add any insight to what is described in existing answers, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57957022/7733418 . Please make your contribution more obvious.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).